# Comparing to a counter which reset

Tags: c++, c, logic, counter

I have an uint32 counter. I read this counter and store it like `startCount = counter;`
Then I do some operations and then check again the counter. If counter is greater than startCount+1 (means counter must be incremented at least twice).

```
if (counter > startCount +1 )
  break;
```

Now the counter will be reseted to zero once it reaches max value for unit32.
To compensate this I have added

```
if (startCount == Max)
  if (counter > 0)
    break;
else
  if (counter > startCount +1) || (counter < startCount)
    break;
```

My question is: is there a better / smarter way to do that?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You can use `uint64_t` for both, but preform the operations modulo `UINT23_MAX`. You can also note, that even when `startCount == UINT23_MAX`, `counter > 0` will still be equivalent to `counter > startCount +1`. But in general, giving advice about "how to do something smarter" requires of you to show why you do it in the first place.

Comment: The counter is internal, I cannot change the type. I am not very good with bit comparsion and I was wondering if this block of code could be reduced to a single statement considering some expreience programmers might have faced simillar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking this below should cover everything

```
if (counter > startCount +1) || ( (counter != startCount) && (counter < startCount +1)) 
    break;
```

`

Comment: ofcourse this assumes that there has atleast been one increment .. maynot be optimum in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
if (counter-startCount > 1) break;
```

or, if I'd want to allow for `int` having more than 32 bits,

```
if ((uint32_t)(counter-startCount) > 1) break;
```

the number of increments computes modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.